# Is my code wrong or it's somehow compiler's fault?

Tags: c

stdout gives:
--------------------------------------------------

Here are the results of all 3 students.
--------------------------------------------------
Although I wanted it to display:
--------------------------------------------------
Here are the results of all 3 students:
 --> 8.75
 --> 9.25
 --> 9.00 
--------------------------------------------------
 Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    /*The grades of 3 students*/
    int grades[3][4] =  {{ 7,10,9,9 }, { 10,10,8,9 }, { 9,8,9,10 } };

    float result1 = (grades[0][0] + grades[0][1] + grades[0][2] + grades[0][3])/4;
    float result2 = (grades[1][0] + grades[1][1] + grades[1][2] + grades[1][3])/4;
    float result3 = (grades[2][0] + grades[2][1] + grades[2][2] + grades[2][3])/4;

    printf("Here are the results of all 3 students:\n");
    /*I stored the results into an array so i can use for loop to display them faster*/
    float a[3]= {result1,result2,result3};

    /*Here i wanted to try to display the results using for loop*/
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i > 3; i++){
        printf(" --> %.2f\n", a[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

What's the problem with the output ?

Comment: When you have a question like in the title, the general rule is to assume the former is true unless solidly proven it is not.

Comment: `/4` --> `/4.` and `i > 3` --> `i < 3`

Comment: Like any other software, compilers do have bugs, but only once in about 30 years have I personally encountered a *bona fide* bug in a mature compiler.

Comment: BTW, if you had run your code through a debugger the answer would have been clear in just a moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
for (i = 0; i > 3; i++)
```

Try  `for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)` (while `i` is less than 3, instead of while `i` is *greater* than 3, which is never...)

Comment: Oops! haven't noticed.Thank You ! Also i changed grades variable type to float because the displayed answer for result2 wasn't correct.At least something i've found by myself.Have a Nice Day!